# save viewport position?

Tags: 3d-view

I would like to know if there is a way to save a viewport view? Not a camera view, but a position in the viewport.

I'm designing an enormous mech warrior and the cockpit is difficult to model. I would ideally like to be able to cycle to the view position inside to model when I need to.

Comment: There might be other ways, but you could try this addon : [http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?218403](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?218403)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save custom view of 3D viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56632/how-to-save-custom-view-of-3d-viewport)