# How to save custom view of 3D viewport?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, add-on

While sculpting, or animating i would have zoomed in rotated and panned to got to a correct view to sculpt or pose. But if i rotate by accident or by need there is no way to go back to that view i had got previously. Are there any script or add on to save custon view of 3D viewport.

Comment: Something like this: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?218403, https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views ?

Comment: Yes @poor this s precisely i wanted and it has more than what i wanted thank you

Comment: You could also create a new camera and press space bar then "align camera to view". This way you would have cameras for each point of view you want

Answer (score 2):

There are addons available to do this. Such as the one available here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?218403. But the functionality is not available by default.

Comment: This is currently a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/357942). Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/110892/edit) your answer to add more detail.